# Trouble with Inserting Graphic

Tags: graphics, formatting

I'm a recent newcomer to LaTex and while I've overcome most of the learning curve, I still encounter some difficulties. For instance, when I run my code to insert a figure:

```
    \begin{figure}
    \caption{Unemployment by Race}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]
    {C:/Users/ageis/Documents/Unemployment by Race.png} 
    \end{figure}
```

The figure is too small and LaTex puts the last half of my image's name into the pdf output beneath the figure.

[image]

I want the image to be at least 550 by 600 in pixels and the "by Race.png" bit in the space beneath the figure to be gone. What can I do?

Comment: Most likely the space in the file name `Unemployment by Race` is responsible for the appearance of `by Race.png` below the image. The image is set to half of the `\textwidth`, if that is too small, you should use another width or the `scale` option

Comment: `\usepackage{grffile}`